# Which control chart can use for monitoring of covariance matrix of cofficient?

Tags: correlation, covariance-matrix, quality-control, monitoring

I have a series of panel data, which includes p cross section and t time. I estimated the covariance matrix of coefficients for periods for periods.

Now my data includes the individual period and the covariance matrix for each time series. What kind of control chart can monitoring the periodic covariance matrix? The data to be controlled is as follows

[image]

Comment: Can you comment on why you want to visualize a covariance matrix over time? A simpler statistic would lend itself to control chart analysis.